# Is it possible to inherit from a Generic with a generical constrained Type?

Tags: delphi, generics, inheritance, types, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have a generic class with type T and a constrained type K like so

```
TGeneric<T; K: T> = class
end;
```

Now I want to inherit from that class:

```
TInheritedGeneric<T; K: T> = class(TGeneric<T, K>)
end;
```

The compiler now tells me "E2515 Type parameter 'K' is not compatible with type 'T'" despite me constraining K to be compatible with T.

Is there any possibility for this to work?